# fscanf() not working with input

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

My Function That writes to the file:

```
Record_t * load_Record(FILE * infile)
{
    Record_t *r;
    char title[TITLE_SIZE];
    char [MEDIUM_SIZE];  
    int ID, rating;
    if ((fscanf(infile,"%d: %s %d", &ID, medium, &rating) != 3 && fgets(title, TITLE_SIZE, infile))){
            return NULL;
    }
    printf("medium is: %s title is: %s\n", medium, title);
    r = create_Record(medium, title);
    set_Record_rating(r, rating);   
    return r;
}
```

where Record_t is defined as:

```
typedef struct Record {
    int ID;
    char * title;
    char * medium;
    int rating;
} Record_t;
```

My main:

```
#include "Record.h"

#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char * title = "The Queen";
    char * medium = "DVD";
    FILE * pfile ;
    struct Record *t = create_Record(medium, title);  //creates a record
    struct Record *s;
    set_Record_rating (t, 3);
    print_Record(t);
    pfile = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    save_Record(t, pfile);
    fclose(pfile);
    destroy_Record(t);  //de-allocates memory
    pfile = fopen("output.txt", "r");
    if(!(s = load_Record(pfile))){
        return 1;
    }
    print_Record(s);
    fclose(pfile);
    destroy_Record(s);      
    return 0;
}
```

output.txt after being written to file:

```
1: DVD 3 The Queen    //checked for excess whitespace(has newline however)
```

Terminal output:

```
1: The Queen DVD 3
medium is: DVD title is: �  //title being saved inappropriately  
                          @
2: �
    @ DVD 3
```

now my *fgets* function is wrong!  For some reason, the title is being saved inappropriately

i am compiling with the following flags:
gcc -ansi -std=c89 -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wall test.c Record.c -o test

where test.c is my main

Comment: You have not allocated any memory for your buffer, `medium`.  In fact, you don't even initialize the variable at all before you used it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char * medium;
```

This should be

```
char medium[SOME_CONSTANT]; // or char* medium = malloc(x); if you need the
                            // memory to persist after the function returns
```

So that you actually have `medium` pointing to some memory you own. As it is now, your pointer is pointing to garbage and you're expecting `fscanf` to save a string in the memory it points to.

If a function ever appears to return a pointer to some magically created memory, you better check the documentation twice (unless that function happens to be the stupid `strdup`). The function either actually expects a pointer to some already-allocated memory, or returns a pointer that points to a block of memory allocated with someone from `malloc`'s family, in which case you need to take responsibility for deallocating it.

Only in very rare circumstances do functions return a pointer to memory without taking a preallocated buffer in and without having `malloc`d it (*especially* when the string that is returned is of unpredictable size like it is for `fscanf`).

Comment: @LeilaHejazi sorry, I can't see what you wrote.

Comment: i changed that check to !=3 and changed 'char medium [7]' but now for some reason my "title" string is not being read correctly....'1: The Queen DVD 3 medium is: DVD title is: (null) 2: (null) DVD 3 '

Comment: and by the check, i mean the suggestion as given by Jonathan just bellow

Comment: @LeilaHejazi what do you think `title` should be? `fgets` reads all data up to the limit you give it

Comment: i set the declaration to char title[LINE_SIZE] (line_size being the maximum title size) but then i got garbage output with the 'printf("medium is: %s title is: %s\n", medium, title);' line, in particular, i got:  'medium is: DVD title is: �
                          @
' from the terminal after that command

Comment: I have my code and terminal output updated. fgets seems to be causing errors now

Comment: @LeilaHejazi first of all, your code has `char [MEDIUM_SIZE];` with the variable name `medium` missing; this indicates that you modified the code before pasting it, which means you could have removed the source of the error. Also, your condition should be `fscanf(infile,"%d: %s %d", &ID, medium, &rating) != 3 || !fgets(title, TITLE_SIZE, infile)`; the way you had it before will only return `NULL` when _both_ fail instead of either one. Please try that and see if `fgets` was failing and you didn't know it.

Comment: you were right.  By failing the first fscanf requirement the way i had it written, the rest of the conditional did not even evaluate.  Your suggestion worked.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You've not allocated a buffer for medium:

```
char * medium;
```

That just creates a pointer to a char called medium, you've not reserved any memory space to read into. This would allocate 256 bytes (allowing you to read up to 256 characters) for medium:

```
medium = malloc(256);
```

Or you can allocate on the stack:

```
char medium[256];
```

Given the issues you're having, I would suggest using allocation on the stack, then just read and write the struct to the file — it saves you from having to parse the fields yourself etc. at expense of disk space (you could be writing out a lot of blank characters) but this wastage would be negligible in this scenario.

```
fwrite(t, sizeof(Record_t), 1, pFile);
fread(t, sizeof(Record_t), 1, pFile);
```

Comment: yes i changed it to 'char medium [APPROPRIATE SIZE]' and the medium read correctly as well as everything else BUT the title that was supposed tob e obtain through fgets.  It not reads into it a null.  and produces the following output i changed that check to !=3 and changed 'char medium [7]' but now for some reason my "title" string is not being read correctly....'1: The Queen DVD 3 medium is: DVD title is: (null) 2: (null) DVD 3 '

Comment: Did you setup a buffer for title too? In your code it's still an uninitialised pointer, which may not crash (depends where it points) but isn't what you want!

Comment: yes i did! I made it an approprate size, but when i did that, it just gave me junk.....like an "� @'

Answer (score 1):

Several ways:

1. You've not allocated the space for it to read the string into.  You need:

   ```
   char medium[100];
   ```
2. You don't check for errors properly:

   ```
   if (!(fscanf(infile,"%d: %s %d", &ID, medium, &rating)
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   if (fscanf(infile,"%d: %s %d", &ID, medium, &rating) != 3 ...
   ```

   You need to explicitly test that you got all the values you expected to read.

That's scratching the surface without a deep analysis of all the code.  Note that you'll need to be sure that you are not trying to return `medium` to the calling code.  This should be OK if `create_record()` does a reasonable job.  It is odd that `create_record()` isn't told the record ID.

Comment: i changed that check to !=3 and changed 'char medium [7]' but now for some reason my "title" string is not being read correctly....'1: The Queen DVD 3
medium is: DVD title is: (null)
2: (null) DVD 3
'

Comment: also, the record is a static variable that increments itself whenever memory is dynamically allocated for a new "record" so that is taken care of automatically with each "create_Record()" function

Comment: Don't forget that the `%s` format reads up to the first white space in the data (or EOF).  While 7 bytes is enough for `The`, it isn't enough space for anything much else.  I'm not convinced you should be using `scanf()` at this point.